# Latin for "Freedom through strength"?

Tags: idiom, translation-check

How would one say "freedom through strength" in Latin?

The word *vis* means strength and *libertas* is liberty/freedom.
So would one say *vis libertas*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you forgot the "through" in there. It's generally not a good idea to translate from one language to another word-for-word, as languages in general don't work that way.

I'd say the best way to translate the phrase wouldn't be "through", but "from":

> Libertas ex vi

This gives the visual impression of liberty made possible out of [the use of/the ability to make use of] force or strength.

Other possibilities include:

> Libertas ex viribus

This is making *vis* plural, which is when it's most often used of physical strength.

You could also possibly do:

> Libertas ex virtute

*Virtus* doesn't really mean our modern "virtue", but rather encapsulates all the qualities that make up a good man, which include not only strength, but moral excellence and courage.